# Error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I work with Entity Framework Core 7 and ASP.NET Core using Razor pages. I get an exception when trying to insert data from Entity Framework Core into the SQL Server table `ZebraSubPrinters`:

> SqlException
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table `'ZebraSubPrinters'` when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Table `ZebraSubPrinters` has `ID` as an identity column

```
    public class ZebraSubPrinters
    {
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string BranchCode { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string PrinterName { get; set; }
        public string PrinterIP { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    }
```

Generic repository used for insert and save data

```
    public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        var result = dbSet.AddAsync(entity).Result.Entity;
   
        return result;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _basecontext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {    
            throw;
        }    
    }
```

Function that does the insert and save using generic repository:

```
public void InsertZebraSubPrinters(ZebraSubPrinters printer)
{ 
    ZebraSubPrinters ZEB = new ZebraSubPrinters();
    ZEB.IsActive = printer.IsActive;
    ZEB.PrinterName = printer.PrinterName;
    ZEB.PrinterIP = printer.PrinterIP;
    ZEB.Category = printer.Category;
    ZEB.DisplayName = printer.DisplayName;
    ZEB.BranchCode = printer.BranchCode;

    aDCSupportUnitOfWork.ZebraSubPrinters.Insert(ZEB);
    aDCSupportUnitOfWork.ZebraSubPrinters.Save();              
}
```

SQL Server Profiler generated error for insert statement above as below:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [ZebraSubPrinters] ([ID], [BranchCode], [Category], [CreatedBy], [CreatedDate], [DisplayName], [IsActive], [PrinterIP], [PrinterName], [SavedDate], [UpdatedBy], [UpdatedDate])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11);
',N'@p0 decimal(18,2),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 datetime2(7),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 bit,@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 nvarchar(4000),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 datetime2(7)',@p0=0,@p1=N'10207',@p2=N'Green',@p3=NULL,@p4='0001-01-01 00:00:00',@p5=N'TANTAWY',@p6=1,@p7=NULL,@p8=NULL,@p9='0001-01-01 00:00:00',@p10=NULL,@p11='0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

How to solve and prevent this error from happen when inserting?

**Updated post**

id column is key and identity 1,1 and I display table with id as

decimal because it exist on database as datatype numeric(18, 0) and

values stored on column id as 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

If I make table  I will make id as integer  but it stored as decimal

Comment: Can you check what's the primary key of your table and what column is identity column? I would think the ID column should be your primary key and identity column in that table, but decimal(18, 2) is an unusual data type for a primary key and identity column.

Comment: yes id is primary key and identity

Comment: id column is key and identity 1,1 and i display table with id ad decimal because it exist on database as datatype numeric(18, 0) and values stored on column id as 1,2,3,4,5 etc

Comment: Well, decimal(18, 2) for an identity column doesn't make sense, so I suspect SQL actually is not able to auto-increment that column. Can you try adding [Precision(18, 0)] attribute on that property and do EF migration?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a decimal identity column?

Comment: So issue happen because datatype is decimal are that you mean because i need to know the reason of error

Comment: I think so, I'd just use an int primary key column. Integer data type is the best choice for most of the tables

Comment: Why is your primary key has a `decimal' type? Change it to int or long so that EF can properly infer it as a primary key.

Comment: That is it a `decimal` isn't an issue, @TanveerBadar . In fact if you are dealing with *very* large numbers it's the right choice as a `decimal` can store a much larger value than a `bigint`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Afd1t9HU) I admit having a scale of anything other than `0` is odd, and that *will* cause an error ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ux5NMc9P)) but the data type alone is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF doesn't know that that ID is an identity column.  By convention it assumes that an `INT ID` is generated by the database, but not a decimal.  So you need to configure it, eg:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ZebraSubPrinters>().Property(x => x.ID).HasPrecision(18,0).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```